# CakePHP Ajax Request not going Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am just trying to test ajax form submit in CakePhp. I have below written code. But ajax is not working.

Error in chrome : 
    **POST `http://localhost/john/Frontends/AjaxFormSubmit` 500 (Internal Server Error)**

**View File**

```
 echo $this->Form->input('appendedInputButton',
         array('id'=>'url','name' => 'AjaxFormSubmit', 'type' => 'text')); 

 echo $this->Form->button('Convert',
         array('id' => 'Convert', 'type' => 'button'));
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Convert').on({
        'click': function () {
            var urlVal = $("#url").val();
            if (urlVal == '' || urlVal == 0) {
                $("#url").focus();
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/john/Frontends/AjaxFormSubmit',
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class FrontendsController extends AppController {

    public $name = 'Frontends';
    public $uses = array();
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');


    public function index() {
        $this - > layout = 'frontend_index_layout';
    }

    public function AjaxFormSubmit() {
        echo "Receiving Via Ajax";
    }
}
```

**Error Log File**

```
2013-08-13 13:41:43 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class JsController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'JsController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
Request URL: /john/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.map
Stack Trace:
#0 G:\wamp\www\john\app\webroot\index.php(111): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2013-08-13 13:42:01 Error: [MissingViewException] View file "G:\wamp\www\john\app\View\Frontends\Ajax_Form_Submit.ctp" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'file' => 'G:\\wamp\\www\\john\\app\\View\\Frontends\\Ajax_Form_Submit.ctp',
)
Request URL: /john/Frontends/AjaxFormSubmit
Stack Trace:
#0 G:\wamp\www\john\lib\Cake\View\View.php(468): View->_getViewFileName(NULL)
#1 G:\wamp\www\john\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(948): View->render(NULL, NULL)
#2 G:\wamp\www\john\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(194): Controller->render()
#3 G:\wamp\www\john\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(FrontendsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#4 G:\wamp\www\john\app\webroot\index.php(111): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#5 {main}
```

Comment: Check your error.log and paste it here.

Comment: @burzum : i have pasted my error.log ..

Comment: *Always* check your error log in these cases and more important: Read it. The reason for your problem is explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error log:

> Error: [MissingViewException] View file
>   "G:\wamp\www\john\app\View\Frontends\Ajax_Form_Submit.ctp" is missing.
>   Exception Attributes: array (   'file' =>
>   'G:\wamp\www\john\app\View\Frontends\Ajax_Form_Submit.ctp', )
>   Request URL: /john/Frontends/AjaxFormSubmit

The issue is pretty clear: Your view file is missing, so create it. I don't know what kind of answer you expect from it but what you do is wrong. If you want to return json [read this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

If you really want to just echo a string you need to call $this->_stop(); after the echo. But instead of returning a meaningless string you should in fact return some kind of json object with a proper message and maybe error code and status so that the response can be handled by your javascript.